# How can I save/load the state of Blender games?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Is there a way to allow a running game (made with Blender) to save its current state?

E.g. when the player wants to shut down the game and, later, restart from that point.

I read in the documentation there are Quit/Restart Game Actuators (restarting the game from the beginning...), but what about "Save/Load"? 
If I well understand, "Save bge.logic.globalDict" is used to save only some game properties.

Thanks and kind regards.

Comment: Short answer is: No as far as I know there is no builtin/native way to directly do this for end users through the UI. It is however totally doable with custom python scripting however. https://www.google.com/search?q=Blender+game+engine+save+load